# Changing MySQL Table based on Date Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is It Possible To Change MySQL Table Column Based On Date Using PHP

For Example

I Want To Change `yearsold = 19` to `yearsold = 20` After 1 Year
So When It Reach 2016 `yearsold` become `20`

Thanks :D

**EDIT**: I Need It To Work Automatically not Having To Visit The Page Over and Over

Comment: why not just save the birthdate and calculate the age, everytime you need it

Comment: You want the "yearsold" column to automatically update?

Answer (score 0):

You could do 1 of 2 things.  First would be save the birthdate and calculate it every time you load the object.

The second would be to create a view that calculates the age as a column in the view, so that every time you select from the view the age is "updated" and displayed correctly.  You can check out the [documentation for mysql views here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).